# Is there any difference in meaning between 「抜け切る」 and 「抜ける」?

Tags: words, manga

Actually, I cannot find the definition of 抜け切る in general sources but some of them suggest the word 抜ける instead.

Here is the sentence where I came across the word in a manga.

> そいでもって　くりかえすけどな...
>
> なんとしても　脱走をやりとげにゃああかん**でえ**　**ぬけきらん**と思うたときは...
>
> 死ぬるかくごくらい　しとくんや

**Extra question**　Does the 「でえ」in the sentence above function as particle 「で」 to indicate means of action which is to escape from a place in this case?

Comment: Extra comment: the でえ is the で used in kansai. It would have the same meaning as だよ here. The 〇〇きる would be to do something to completeness, I'll let you match it to your context.

Answer (score 5):

切る in this context is like *up* in *eat up* (as opposed to *eat*) or *out* in *sell out* (as opposed to *sell*), which adds the meaning of *thoroughly/completely* to the original verb.

> - 飲みきる to drink up
> - 疲れきる to be exhausted
> - 最後までやり切る to push on to the end

So this ぬけきらん means "cannot go through it (e.g., a tunnel) completely".

でえ/で is not the place marker, but yet another sentence-ending particle like ね, よ, わ, and な. It's used mainly by "tough" guys, but in some dialects also by women.