# Meaning of 荷重が乗りきる

Tags: particles, verbs, particle-が, sports, compound-verbs

Context: a boxer has just landed a great uppercut with an upward movement. His father describes the punch in this way:

> 荷重が乗りきってからの急激な〝縦〟一閃

I think here 乗りきる means "to overcome", so my rough translation attempt would be

> (After) overcoming his weight, he did a sudden and quick upward/vertical movement

but I am confused by the が after 荷重. Shouldn't it be 荷重を乗りきってから? Is 荷重 the subject? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWl7R.jpg) you can see the whole page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 乗り切る is not "to overcome", but a simple combination of 乗る + [切る](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33791/5010), "(for power/force/etc) to be put/applied/loaded" + "completely/fully". 荷重が乗り切ってから is "after his weight was fully put onto the punch". It can be rephrased as 荷重を乗せ切ってから ("after loading/putting his weight fully onto the punch").