# Meaning of 譲る in 譲りきれない思い出

Tags: meaning, connotation

This is a part from a song text by [Aimyon](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/aimyon/becauseiminlovekoiwoshitakara.html):

> 忘れられないものなどなくて
>
> **譲りきれない**思い出ばかりで
>
> いい加減に諦めなさいなんて
>
> 簡単に言わないで

So far I understand that きれない is used to modify the verb in front (here 譲る) so that the action continues on. But what is the meaning of 譲る?
My dictionaries tell me of several meanings:

1. to hand over/transfer/turn over/bequeath/convey
2. to give up (e.g. one's seat) / give way
3. to yield/concede/give ground/surrender
4. to sell
5. to postpone/put off

But I don't see which of those meanings would work on "memories". The translation I found:

> There are only memories you don't want to give up

points to the second meaning, but somehow I had the feeling that 譲る is only used when the object in question is not lost, but transferred or given to somebody else. Taking the meaning of the translation 譲る would be used in the sense of loosing the object.

So:

- does 譲る have also the meaning that the object can get lost in the process

or

- is the translation I found for the phrase not ideal

or

- is this song-text Japanese?

Comment: FWIW I'll vote for sense #2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

思い出を譲る is definitely not a common phrase, and I would say even a native speaker can only guess the most plausible meaning from the context. And I also think it basically refers to the same thing as 思い出を忘れる here. Although 譲る does not normally mean the object gets lost completely, I cannot think of any other possibilities. It's impossible to give one's memory to someone else, and even if were possible, there is no one who wants the memory of this person in the song.

Note that this 切る means "completely/thoroughly" (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33791/5010)).